# my binary search tree program stopped working (C)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

For some reason the insertion part of the code is not working as intended. When I run the program it just gives an error "bst.exe has stopped working" and it happens in this function. The whole idea of this portion of the code is to ITERATIVELY insert a new node and update the root.

```
static NODE *insert_i(NODE *r, int x)
{
    NODE *leaf;

    if(r == NULL)
    {
        leaf = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        leaf->left = NULL;
        leaf->right = NULL;
        leaf->val = x;
        count++;
        return leaf;
    }

    while(r)
    {
        if(r->val == x)
            return r;

        if(x < r->val && r->left != NULL)
            r = r->left;

        else if(x > r->val && r->right != NULL)
            r = r->right;
    }

    leaf = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    leaf->left = NULL;
    leaf->right = NULL;
    leaf->val = x;
    count++;

    if(x < r->val)
        r->left = leaf;

    else
        r->right = leaf;

    return r;
}


void bst_insert(BST_PTR t, int x)
{
    t->root = insert_i(t->root, x);
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it under a debugger?

Comment: If only there was a tool that could step through your code line by line and let you check the values of variables in an ad hoc manner :-)

Comment: Think about the loop condition, what will the value or `r` be when the loop exits?

Comment: while(r) smells fishy

Comment: Don't give your variable nonsense names like `r` and `x`, then you might already have solved this bug. Suppose the prototype has been `insert_i (NODE* const parent, int new_val);` instead. Then you would had forced yourself not to write this bug.

Comment: So, you approach, instead of that all-so-hard-work debugging, is to continually repost your ongoing problems to SO until everything works to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, outside the loop

```
if(x < r->val)
    r->left = leaf;

else
    r->right = leaf;
```

`r` is NULL. So, if you access `r->val`, it will crash.

Try to keep track of the parent as shown below.

```
NODE *leaf;
NODE * par

while(r)
{
    if(r->val == x)
        return r;

    par = r;
    if(x < r->val && r->left != NULL)
        r = r->left;

    else if(x > r->val && r->right != NULL)
        r = r->right;
}

leaf = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
leaf->left = NULL;
leaf->right = NULL;
leaf->val = x;
count++;


if(x < par->val)
    par->left = leaf;

else
    par->right = leaf;

return r;
```